# How to select information from database that is 1 day, 1 week old?

Tags: php, mysql, date

I need to modify my query to select information that is 1 day, 1 week old.
I have 2 tables one for votes and other for articles, and It should look at st_date from articles table.

Query

```
SELECT stories.*, SUM(votes.vote_value) as 'total_votes' 
FROM stories 
    JOIN votes ON stories.id = votes.item_name 
GROUP BY stories.id 
ORDER BY total_votes DESC LIMIT 10
```

Database Structure:

**Stories table**

[image: Stories table]

**Votes Table**
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A week is always 7 days, so you actually need data from 8 days old.

```
WHERE st_date >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 8 DAY)
```

Your full query would be:

```
SELECT stories.*, SUM(votes.vote_value) as 'total_votes' 
FROM stories 
    JOIN votes ON stories.id = votes.item_name 
WHERE stories.st_date >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 8 DAY)
GROUP BY stories.id 
ORDER BY total_votes DESC LIMIT 10
```

Comment: where would I place this in query?

Comment: in face, mysql also supports WEEK, if you should happen to need it. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Answer (score 1):

Looks something like...

WHERE st_date >= now, interval 8 day

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a WHERE statement 
something like

```
SELECT stories.*, SUM(votes.vote_value) as 'total_votes' 
FROM stories 
JOIN votes ON stories.id = votes.item_name 
WHERE PERIOD_DIFF(CURRENT_DATE , stories.st_date) <  1
GROUP BY stories.id 
ORDER BY total_votes DESC LIMIT 10
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using `DATEDIF()` mysql function

Answer (score 0):

you can find the result between any date range use

```
st_date >= start_date AND st_date <=end_date
```